# ASP.NET MVC create "Add to favorite" button for logged in users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement a function for my ASP.NET MVC project, where users see all available movies and then can click a button, which would add that movie to their own "Favorites", which would be in a different page, so that it is easily accessible. Problem is, that I can't think of any other idea as implementing a database table between user and movies.

When in "Favorites" page, I would like for the user to be able to click on the movie, but it would display detailed, already existing info. A simple redirect most likely, but I do not know if using anything else than db would make that more complicating.

Is there any other option, than to use database solution and pass movie info to a new table for each specific user? It seems like a rather impractical solution, because there could be a lot of similar data, just different users.

To note, I would like for the data to stay as long as the user doesn't remove that favorited item from their "Favorites" list, but it also could be time based, perhaps session or something like that (I am mainly interested in the possibility. If there is some super easy way to do this, but session/time based, I can just have that stated somewhere). I would assume, that a db solution is the best case for "infinite-as-long-as-user-wants" time, but maybe I am wrong and it is somehow possible to do with a different solution. As I said - only trying to achieve this, and have not gone past idea stage, so any help is appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT: Seems like there is a possibility to use Sessions or Cookies. As I understand, the difference between those is time. Sessions is 20 minutes and Cookies can be defined up to a year (could be wrong, but from some guide it stated that, and showcased 30days at least).
Is it possible to achieve, what I wish to do with favoriting using cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are per browser. Sessions are also per browser session and live as long as `min(session lifetime, storage lifetime)`. By default, session data is stored in-process, so as soon as your app pool or web server restarts, your users lose their favorites.

Worse: their favorites are (indirectly) stored per browser. So if they favorite something on their mobile, they can't find it back on desktop and vice versa.

If you already have a database that stores users and movies, the only sensible thing would be a UserMovies table, that stores the userId and movieId to link favorites to users.

That is not "a lot of data" unless you reach millions of users having thousands of favorites, and then still, there are indexes for that. Databases are designed to store a lot of data. Cookies and sessions aren't.

Comment: Thank you for this insight. I assumed so, but since I never used Cookies, thought maybe that could be a viable option. Marked as answer.

Comment: Perhaps I should make this as another question, but how could I make favoriting instant and without refreshing the browser? Click the favourite button and not refresh the page, so that you could select multiple movies and view them all later in the "Favorites" page. JavaScript?

Comment: Yeah that's going to require JavaScript.